# Sam Sparro - Black and Gold

Tags: genre, recording, release, record-labels, record

I have searched everywhere on YouTube, but could not find the original song video by Sam Sparro, the one where the black Mercedes car with gold metal strips walls along the stage, and then the fish rotate out of the ocean, and Sam Sparro, with the black hat and costume, snaps his fingers as he sings.

Any idea where I can get it (if not available on YouTube)?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a link to the video on [Vimeo](https://vimeo.com/52122271)! I went to the website of the original video's director, Mariah Garnett, and it's listed under [her music videos](http://mariahgarnett.com/music-videos/). It's the third one from the top.